# how can make executable python file

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have a simple python project and i need a executable file from windows and linux.
how can make a executable file ?
i see `PyInstaller` but this just build executable file from windows and `.exe` file is huge for my app.
my app need command line for working but i want my executable file don't show command window. How can i do it?
i think [bdist](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/builtdist.html) id better for me but this command where is save location for executable files?

Comment: I have no idea if this suits your needs based on your description, but open terminal in the file's directory and use `chmod +x myPythonFile.py` to make an executable .py file in linux. I had some frustrating problems taking a python script I had written in a Windows-based editor over to linux due to carriage returns being different. Searching `dos2unix` in Google for the relevant approach for your setup might save you some time if you're having issues.

Comment: i need executable file like .exe a user can double click on file and run the app.